# What is the logic behind (' + str(i) + ')?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, and stamp upon this line:

```
print('My name is')
for i in range(5):
   print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')
```

I don't understand this part  (' + str(i) + ')'),  to be more specific,  the + sign before and after str(i) [especially the + sign after str(i)].

I know the + sign is for strings concatenation,  But in the above line,  what is combined with what?

And what is the difference between the first example and say:

```
print('My name is')
for i in range(5):
    print('Jimmy five times ' + str(i))
```

Can someone give an example for a similar but complex example for such use?

Thanks.

**edit:**
I realized that the string is **Jimmy Five Times (** ,not **Jimmy Five Times**, that left and right brackets confused me. Thanks all for your quick responses.

Comment: Have you compared the output of both of your examples? That should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: There are 3 strings concatenated in the first example: (1) `'Jimmy Five Times ('`, (2) `str(i)`, and (3) `')'`. Also the better way to write this is `print(f'Jimmy Five Times ({i})')` and not use string concatenation at all.

Comment: An alternate would be an f-string like `print(f'Jimmy Five Times ({i})')` where the `{i}` tells python to substitute the current value of `i` in that string position.

Comment: and if you solved it, please mark one of the answers accepted(by clicking the check mark) or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

`+` concatenates strings, or if operands are numbers then adds them. Here you need to do `str(i)` because if `i` is not a string, then python tries to add them as integers, which is not possible. And the ending `+ ')'` will add a closing parentheses to the string, and second example does not add parentheses. See yourself, first one will:

```
My name is
Jimmy Five Times (0)
Jimmy Five Times (1)
Jimmy Five Times (2)
Jimmy Five Times (3)
Jimmy Five Times (4)
```

And second one:

```
My name is
Jimmy five times 0
Jimmy five times 1
Jimmy five times 2
Jimmy five times 3
Jimmy five times 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The sign `+` in the context of strings is used for string concatenation.

Specifically, in this example, the `+` operand is not defined for string and int (`i` is an integer) so you first have to convert it to string by `str(i)` and then you can contact the strings.

Answer (score 0):

For the first code mentioned, the first string 'Jimmy Five Times (' is concatenated with `str(i)` and then this `str(i)` is further concatenated with ')' so the final output is :

```
Jimmy Five Times (0)
Jimmy Five Times (1)
Jimmy Five Times (2)
Jimmy Five Times (3)
Jimmy Five Times (4)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

The sign + in the context of strings is used for string concatenation.

Specifically, in this example, the + operand is not defined for string and int (i is an integer) so you first have to convert it to string by `str(i)` and then you can contact the strings.

#### Output

First one's output:

```
My name is
Jimmy Five Times (0)
Jimmy Five Times (1)
Jimmy Five Times (2)
Jimmy Five Times (3)
Jimmy Five Times (4)
```

And second one's output:

```
My name is
Jimmy five times 0
Jimmy five times 1
Jimmy five times 2
Jimmy five times 3
Jimmy five times 4
```

#### Better solutions

using `f'` strings python 3.6 up

```
print(f'Jimmy Five Times ({i})')
```

using `.format`

```
print('My name is')
for i in range(5):
   print('Jimmy Five Times ({0})'.format(i))
```